# SKSpriteNode Automated movement

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm making my first game, it will be similar to Mario. (using swift)

Have started to make some enemies they will need to move left and right and respond to collisions, I can do this for my player node as I call player.update() function from the SKScene update function,

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
{
    player.update()
}
```

My question is:

For enemyX , how can I get the node to update since SKSpriteNode does not have a default update function that can be overridden and from my game scene

I do not want really write some thing like:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
{
    player.update()
    enemyX.update()
    enemyY.update()
    enemy001.update()
    ...
    enemy100.update
}
```

Do you see what I mean, how do I get around this, does SKSpriteNode need to be a different class?

Maybe actions?

```
let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX( 200, y:0, duration: 5)
self.runAction(moveLeft, completion: {
    print("----> move left Complete")
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just thinking Could I use a run forever function i.e ```self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever( SKAction.runBlock({ self.enemyLogic() })));```

Comment: Normally you decide where you want your enemy to move to, and call `SKAction.moveTo`, `SKAction.moveToX`, or `SKAction.moveToY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you subclass `SKSpriteNode` and and an update method inside that class.  then in your update method in your scene you do exactly what you said

```
player.update()
enemy.update()
```

etc.

Don't recommend using SKAction unless the behavior of your enemies is extremely simple.

Comment: So I guess I add all enemies that spawn to an array, then iterate through the the array, if enemy's position is past the players X or too far in front of the player's X position just skip that update - is it pretty much something like that? Are there any built in functions that will help with this? - thanks

Comment: yeah i would iterate through the array of enemies and call update on each one doing whatever it is i need to do for my particular game